# Iscroll only working after orientation was changed? in iphone , ipad

Tags: cordova, iscroll

Iscroll only starts after orientation was change, with out orientation change it will behave like rubber band.

Comment: im facing the same issue.. anything on this yet?

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem. It turned out that I was calling iScroll too early. My solution was to either wrap the iScroll in a timeout like cubiq suggests on the site, or call .refresh() on your iScroll once everything has finished rendering.

You can test this by opening up console and calling yourScroll.refresh();